# How to retrieve commas separated values from PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce, database-normalization

Currently I'm working on an E-Commerce website, and I've successfully inserted dynamic multi select dropdown values into database with implode. And they look like `2, 3, 4`.

Now I want to retrieve those values without comma and spaces and show them as buttons, I tried using explode but it is not working.

**Here are my tables:**

[Dynamic Sizes Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6VO5.png)

[T-shirts Table Where Sizes Are Stored in "tshirt_size" Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC24C.png)

**Here's the code which I use to insert the size values**

```
// Inserting Multiple Sizes into Database

        $tshirt_sizes_array = array();

        foreach($_POST['t_size'] as $key=>$value){
            $tshirt_sizes_array[].= $value;
            $tshirt_sizes = implode(', ', $tshirt_sizes_array);
        }
```

Now I want to retrieve those values with explode, but it is not working, **here's the code below I'm using to retrieve the size values**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_sizes)){
     $pr_sizes = explode(", ", $row['size_title']);
}
```

It only retrieves the value if a single size is stored in the field. Like `2` or `3`, and doesn't work when there are multiple values as `2, 3, 4`.

[This is exactly what I want to achieve!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmYpB.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

**Updates**

My SQL Query:

```
$t_sizes = $row_t['tshirt_size'];

$get_sizes = "SELECT * FROM tshirt_sizes WHERE size_id = $t_sizes";

while($row_t4 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_sizes)){

                $pr_sizes = $row_t4['size_title'];

}
```

**Get Tshirt Model Code**

```
function get_tshirt_modal(){
    
    global $conn;

        $get_t = "SELECT * FROM tshirts ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6";
        $run_t = mysqli_query($conn, $get_t);

        while($row_t = mysqli_fetch_array($run_t)){

            $t_id = $row_t['tshirt_id'];
            $t_name = $row_t['tshirt_title'];
            $t_price = $row_t['tshirt_price'];
            $t_sale_price = $row_t['tshirt_sale_price'];
            $t_pre_1 = $row_t['tshirt_preview1'];
            $t_pre_2 = $row_t['tshirt_preview2'];
            $t_status = $row_t['tshirt_status'];
            $t_desc = $row_t['tshirt_desc'];
            $t_cat = $row_t['tshirt_category'];
            $t_sizes = $row_t['tshirt_size'];

            $get_status = "SELECT * FROM product_status WHERE p_status_id = $t_status";
            $run_get_status = mysqli_query($conn, $get_status);

            $get_cat = "SELECT * FROM tshirt_categories WHERE tshirt_category_id = $t_cat";
            $run_get_cat = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cat);

            $get_sizes = "SELECT * FROM tshirt_sizes WHERE size_id IN($t_sizes)";
            $run_get_sizes = mysqli_query($conn, $get_sizes);

            while($row_t2 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_status)){

                $pr_status = $row_t2['p_status_title'];
                $pr_status_lowercase = strtolower($pr_status);

            while($row_t3 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_cat)){

                $pr_cat = $row_t3['tshirt_category_title'];

            while($row_t4 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_sizes)){

                $pr_sizes = $row_t4['size_title'];
                foreach($pr_sizes as $key=>$value){
            
    echo "<div class='modal fade product-modal' id='productModal$t_id' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true'>
            <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-body'>
                        <button type='button' class='close custom-close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                            <span aria-hidden='true'><i class='dl-icon-close'></i></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                <div class='product-image-carousel nav-vertical-center nav-style-1'>
                                    <div class='product-image'>
                                        <div class='product-image--holder'>
                                            <a href='product-details.php?t_id=$t_id'>
                                                <img src='images/tshirt_preview_images/$t_pre_1' alt='Product Image' class='primary-image'>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>";
                                        if (!empty($pr_status_lowercase == 'none')) {
                                            // Don't Show Any Badge
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<span class='product-badge $pr_status_lowercase'>$pr_status</span>";
                                        }
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                <div class='modal-box product-summary'>
                                    <h3 class='product-title mb--15'>$t_name</h3>
                                    <span class='product-price-wrapper mb--20'>
                                        <span class='money'>₹$t_sale_price</span>
                                        <span class='product-price-old'>
                                            <span class='money'>₹$t_price</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class='product-action d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb--30' style='margin-top:15px'>
                                        <div class='quantity'>
                                            <input type='number' class='quantity-input' name='qty' id='qty' value='1' min='1'>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-style-1 btn-semi-large add-to-cart'
                                            onclick='window.location.href='cart.php''>
                                            Add To Cart
                                        </button>
                                        <a href='wishlist.php?t_id=$t_id'><i class='dl-icon-heart2'></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class='product-short-description mb--25 mb-md--20'>$t_desc</p>
                                    <div class='product-meta float-left'>
                                        <span class='sku_wrapper font-size-12'>Tags -  
                                            <a href='shop-sidebar.html' rel='tag'>Style Blogger </a>
                                            <a href='shop-sidebar.html' rel='tag'>Style </a>
                                            <a href='shop-sidebar.html' rel='tag'>Trending</a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class='posted_in font-size-12'>Category -  
                                            <a href='shop-sidebar.php' rel='tag'>$pr_cat</a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class='posted_in font-size-12'>Available Sizes -  
                                            <a href='shop-sidebar.php' rel='tag'>$value</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='product-share-box float-right'>
                                        <span class='font-size-12'>Let's Vibe Humanity</span>
                                        <!-- Social Icons Start Here -->
                                        <ul class='social social-small'>
                                            <li class='social__item'>
                                                <a href='https://facebook.com' class='social__link'>
                                                    <i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class='social__item'>
                                                <a href='https://twitter.com' class='social__link'>
                                                    <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class='social__item'>
                                                <a href='https://plus.google.com' class='social__link'>
                                                    <i class='fa fa-google-plus'></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class='social__item'>
                                                <a href='https://plus.google.com' class='social__link'>
                                                    <i class='fa fa-pinterest-p'></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <!-- Social Icons End Here -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update Final**

**Guys here's the working code**

```
$availableSizeArr = [];
            
     while($row_t4 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_sizes)){

     $pr_sizes = $row_t4['size_title'];
     $availableSizeArr[] = "<a href='shop-sidebar.php' rel='tag'>$pr_sizes</a>";

}
```

$availableSizes = implode(', ', $availableSizeArr);

A **HUGE** thanks to @biesior for the help!

Comment: You should re-structure your database design (normalize it) so that you never store comma-separated values.

Comment: If you're at the design stage, stop now and redesign the database so that it doesn't store multiple values in a single column. It's not a good database design, and it makes retrieval more complex. You should really have a separate table containing sizes. ETA as @Qirel said above.

Comment: Thank you, so how can I achieve that? Should I add more columns to the tshirts table as `size_s`, `size_m`, `size_l`, `size_xl`? And use boolean to know if the sizes are available or not? How can I fix this?

Comment: You could have a table that combines products with sizes. It can hold the product id and the size id. Sizes are not part of the product. If you have 3 sizes available for a product, it will then have 3 rows in the table. It's a many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: Here is a question you might ask yourself. "If I run out of stock on size M Batman shirts, how will my e-commerce site know to stop accepting orders for them?"

Comment: @biesior I am a very beginner in PHP/MySQL, I'm kinda confused what to do and proceed further. Even if I get this solved, will it be ethical? Or restructuring my database is the right thing? Please let me know...

Comment: Update your question, and show us SQL statement you're using now, I think I have a solution. Keep in mind that @Pierre's advice about changing DB structure isn't that bad, however, it's not always required. I'm asking for SQL sample as just don't want to guess ;) Note that updated @_Philip's answer also brings some clues I would check.

Comment: @biesior sure, I'll update my question! And show you my SQL statement, thank you to all for the help though <3

Comment: **Debugging** is a key, using `var_dump($get_sizes)` would give you a clue. I'm pretty sure that should be something like `SELECT * FROM tshirt_sizes WHERE size_id IN(1,2,3)` instead of `SELECT * FROM tshirt_sizes WHERE size_id = 1,2,3`

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're keeping your comma-separated values in a field that means you should use `IN` expression instead of simple `=` comparator. Like in some [Googled solution](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php), your query would look like:

```php
if($t_sizes != ''){
    $get_sizes = "SELECT * FROM tshirt_sizes WHERE size_id IN($t_sizes)";
}
```

**Note:** although in **this** case you don't work with incoming user data, it is always better to use prepared statements instead. Your homework for today is inspecting whole your code and replacing raw queries with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Comment: Hey man it's working! But it's only retrieving first value of an array, how can I fix this? Can foreach loop fix this? Thanks a ton, you are about to save my life...

Comment: I tried with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` still it isn't working, but now it is atleast showing us the first value of an array, I did what you told. When I added foreach loop it's not working, I'll upload my table somewhere and notify...

Comment: How can we move to chat?

Answer (score 1):

As other people mentioned in the comments, you should consider restructuring the DB in order to normalize it.

One solution which is very close to yours is to use the SET datatype (it is available in MySQL/MariaDB and it is very useful for cases like yours when you have fixed set of values to store). Here is how:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sizes SET("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL")
);

INSERT INTO shirts(name, sizes) VALUES
("shirt1", "S,M,L"),
("shirt2", "L,XL"),
("shirt3", "M");

SELECT * FROM shirts;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | sizes |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | shirt1 | S,M,L |
|  2 | shirt2 | L,XL  |
|  3 | shirt3 | M     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

It is much easier to manage it that way and it is very efficient in respect of storage. And yes, it's not far from what you already have as code too! And you do not need a "Dynamic Sizes Table" table at all - everything is stored inside the tshirts table. My proposal is based on the assumption that you will never add new tshirt sizes - they are always a fixed set (like you are never going to add "XXXXXXXXL" in future). Finally - it's really simple to search inside. For example if a user wants to search for shirts only in size "M", you can fetch list like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shirts
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("M", sizes)>0;
```

If you must have dynamic tshirt sizes, then you should make a M:M relation between the sizes table and the shirts table. It can be done like that:

```
CREATE TABLE shirts_sizes(
    size_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    size_title VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO shirts_sizes(size_title) VALUES
("XS"),("S"),("M"),("L"),("XL"),("XXL"),("XXXL");

CREATE TABLE shirts(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO shirts(name) VALUES
("shirt1"),
("shirt2"),
("shirt3");

CREATE TABLE shirts_sizes_availability(
    size_id INT NOT NULL,
    shirt_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(size_id, shirt_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(size_id) REFERENCES shirts_sizes(size_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(shirt_id) REFERENCES shirts(id)
);

INSERT INTO shirts_sizes_availability(shirt_id,size_id) VALUES
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5),(3,3);
```

Note that now we insert the specific shirt size in separate row in the connecting table and NOT separated by comma values. Here is how to extract them later:

```
SELECT shirts.id, shirts.name, shirts_sizes.size_title
FROM shirts
JOIN shirts_sizes_availability
  ON shirts.id = shirts_sizes_availability.shirt_id
JOIN shirts_sizes
  ON shirts_sizes_availability.size_id = shirts_sizes.size_id;
+----+--------+------------+
| id | name   | size_title |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | shirt1 | S          |
|  1 | shirt1 | M          |
|  1 | shirt1 | L          |
|  2 | shirt2 | L          |
|  2 | shirt2 | XL         |
|  3 | shirt3 | M          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Based on the previous example, if you search for shirts only of size "M", you can add a WHERE clause easily here. And iff you want to combine them comma-separated like in the previous example, you can use GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SELECT shirts.id, shirts.name, GROUP_CONCAT(shirts_sizes.size_title) AS sizes
FROM shirts
JOIN shirts_sizes_availability 
  ON shirts.id = shirts_sizes_availability.shirt_id
JOIN shirts_sizes
  ON shirts_sizes_availability.size_id = shirts_sizes.size_id
GROUP BY shirts.id;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | sizes |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | shirt1 | S,M,L |
|  2 | shirt2 | L,XL  |
|  3 | shirt3 | M     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Despite all of what I said above, I do not see why explode will not work. Here is a simplified example where it works fine:

```
//You should have fetched that string from the DB
$row['size_title'] = "S,L,XL";
//Now I explode it
$pr_sizes = explode(",", $row['size_title']);
//And each element is stored correctly
echo $pr_sizes[0]."<br />"; //prints "S"
echo $pr_sizes[1]."<br />"; //prints "L"
echo $pr_sizes[2];          //prints "XL"
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is the database structure does not respect [the first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) you must not have a field of type text/varchar acting as an array comma separated because a table's field must contain only atomic (indivisible values)  to avoid data redundancy and improve data integrity. I suggest you remove the field **tshirt_size** and create a table **tshirt_size** (if you only sell tshirts)

```
CREATE TABLE tshirt_size
(
    tshirt_id int, // for tshirt 1
    size_id int, // of size L
    stock int // I have 3 in stock
)
```

When you don't respect the fundamentals of data then coding becomes really difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me! I'll change the database design and keep this in mind from next time :) And what if I want to sell t-shirts and some other stuff too? Will I have to create separate table for example, as `jeans_size` for jeans as well?